# How to distinguish a source path from a remote path in a custom Ansible module

Tags: module, ansible

It's my understanding that Ansible modules are executed on the remote machine. So I would think to access files on the remote machine I would just use standard Python I/O. I am curious as to how I can access files on the source machine during a custom Ansible module. I have looked through the copy module as well as others, but cannot seem to find the "magic" that allows for something like this. At no point does it seem like the file actually jumps hosts.

Answer (score 0):

> It's my understanding that Ansible modules are executed on the remote machine. So I would think to access files on the remote machine I would just use standard Python I/O.

That's correct. Modules execute on the remote host. Lookups execute
on the control host.

> I am curious as to how I can access files on the source machine during a custom Ansible module.

You can't. Your module is running on a remote machine and does not
have access to local files.  You would either use a `copy` or
`template` task to move a file to the remote system before running
your module, or you would pass in the *content* as an argument to your
module.

> I have looked through the copy module as well as others...

The `copy` mechanism is an *action plugin*. The implementation is
[here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py). I would not suggest that you attempt to implement a new feature using that mechanism; instead, rely on other tasks to move files around.